# Is $f:A\to B$ is an injective finite type homomorphism of integral domains, then $\text{Frac}(B)$ is finite dimensional over $\text{Frac}(A)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

Let $A$ and $B$ be integral domains, such that $f:A\to B$ is an injective finite-type homomorphism. Then there is an induced map $\text{Frac}(A)\to\text{Frac}(B)$ by the universal property of localisation (since $f$ is injective).

Why is $\text{Frac}(B)/\text{Frac}(A)$ a finite field extension? What is its degree?

I was thinking that since $A\to B$ is finite type, $B\cong A[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$ where $I$ does not contain any non-zero element of $A$, and localisation commutes with quotients, so that $$\text{Frac}(B)\cong A[x_1,\dots,x_n]_I/I A[x_1,\dots,x_n]_I,$$

and that $\text{Frac}(A)\to A[x_1,\dots,x_n]_I\twoheadrightarrow \text{Frac}(B)$ had first map factoring through $\text{Frac}(A)[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to A[x_1,\dots,x_n]_I$, and if this was itself surjective, then $\text{Frac}(A)[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to \text{Frac}(B)$ would at least make $\text{Frac}(B)$ finite dimensional over $\text{Frac}(A)$, but it wouldn't tell me what the degree is.

Comment: What makes you think this is true?

Comment: @EricWofsey I was learning about proper pushforward of $k$-cycles, and I thought if $f:X\to Y$ is proper between locally finite type schemes, and $Z\subset X$ is an integral closed subscheme, then giving $f(Z)$ the reduced induced closed subscheme structure we have a morphism on the generic points, giving an extension of function fields $R(Z)/R(f(Z))$, and I think this is finite (which I thought would follow by using the finite type property of a proper morphism - so I took an affine open containing the generic point of $f(Z)$, and an affine open containing the generic point of $Z$)

Comment: No, $R(Z)/R(f(Z))$ is not finite in general.  For instance, consider $X=Z=\mathbb{P}^1$ and $Y=\mathbb{A}^0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.  For a very simple example, if $B=A[x]$, then the fraction field of $B$ is $K(x)$ where $K$ is the fraction field of $A$, which is not a finite extension of $K$.  It is true iff $B$ is algebraic over $A$, since a finitely generated field extension is finite iff it is algebraic.

Comment: Following up my comment to the OP, I guess I didn't encode in my algebraic case that $Z$ and $f(Z)$ are supposed to have the same dimension. Which might make this basically tautological, since then the transcendence degree of the extension is $0$

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise why the definition of proper pushforward was split into cases until now!

Comment: Actually, I still have one concern. I only know tautologically that $R(Z)/R(f(Z))$ is algebraic if $Z$ and $f(Z)$ have the same dimension (not necessarily that they are finite), so it's still not clear to me that $R(Z)/R(f(Z))$ would be finite in my case (but otherwise proper pushforward doesn't make sense) is it true that if $f:A\to B$ is an injective finite-type homomorphism of integral $k$-algebras, such that $\text{Frac}(A)$ and $\text{Frac}(B)$ have the same transcendence degree over $k$, that $\text{Frac}(B)/\text{Frac}(A)$ is a finite extension?

Comment: By the way, I don't know if it's convention on math stackexchange to post my slightly different question as a new question, or to just tie it up here in the comments. (I guess it might depend on how non-trivial the change is?)

Comment: Since $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-algebra, $Frac(B)$ is a finitely generated field extension of $Frac(A)$ (use the same finite set of generators).  So since it's an algebraic extension, this means it is finite.  (As for your last question, either way is fine--but if you ask in the comments, you're not likely to get an answer from anyone other than me.)

Comment: This might be dumb, but, where $S=A-\{0\}$, I would only expect $S^{-1}B\subset \text{Frac}(B)$ to be generated over $\text{Frac}(A)$ by the same generators, not all of $\text{Frac}(B)$. (I do agree that if $\text{Frac}(B)$ was finitely generated over $\text{Frac}(A)$ then I could use Zariski's lemma to deduce it's a finite extension)

Comment: Oh right, I found a related math stack exchange post that explains that $S^{-1}B$ is a finite dimensional domain over $\text{Frac}(A)$, so that it is necessarily a field. Since $S$ contains no zero divisors, $B\hookrightarrow S^{-1}B$, and all non-zero elements of $B$ inside $S^{-1}B$ are invertible, so that $\text{Frac}(B)\to S^{-1}B$ is induced, and $S^{-1}B$ is thus a field extension of $\text{Frac}(B)$. But $f(S)\subset B-\{0\}$ so that $f(S)^{-1}B\subset \text{Frac}(B)$ and hence $S^{-1}B\cong \text{Frac}(B)$ as required.

Comment: So $\text{Frac}(B)$ is finitely generated over $\text{Frac}(A)$, and by Zariski's lemma this means that $\text{Frac}(B)$ is a finite field extension of $\text{Frac}(A)$ as asserted.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's easier than that: Frac(B) is trivially generated as a *field* (not ring!) extension of Frac(A) by the same generators.  But then, since it's an algebraic extension, being finitely generated as a field extension implies it is a finite extension.

Comment: I can only see $S^{-1}B\subset \text{Frac}(B)$ being generated over $\text{Frac}(A)$ by the same generators. The induced map being defined from first of all $A[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to B$ given by $x_i\mapsto b_i$, and then

$$\phi:\text{Frac}(A)[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to \text{Frac}(B)$$
given by $\phi(a/b)=\phi(a)/\phi(b)$ and $\phi(x_i)=b_i/1$

Where this only hits $S^{-1}B$ inside the fraction field of $B$

(My argument above shows that $S^{-1}B=\text{Frac}(B)$, but I don't think it's clear otherwise - I mean to say I think it's not easier than my argument above)

Comment: "Generated as a field" means you're allowed to take inverses.  So B already generates Frac(B) as a field.

Comment: Oh right, I missed that distinction!

Comment: Thanks again, that is indeed much easier!